# How to replace HTML body to text body including line break in angular?

Tags: html, angular

My HTML Content is like this:
"`<p>Hi&nbsp;Bhavna,</p><p>&nbsp;</p> <p>You are invited to give the&nbsp;employee survey 2022 survey. To start the survey please click on below link.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p><a href='http://localhost:4401/survey/384/eskl60ke5nk' target='_blank'>Click here.</a></p>`"

which I want it to be like this using angular.

Hi Bhavna,

You are invited to give the employee survey 2022 survey. To start the survey please click on below link.

Click here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Angular by using `[innerHTML]` property binding , but make sure you call `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` over `sanitizer` dependency. Consider creating `safehtml` pipe for the same

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

 constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

 public transform(value: any, type: string): any {
     return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div [innerHTML]="html | safeHtml"></div>
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-poulbq)